# Query-replace in multiple LaTeX environments, narrowing each in turn

Tags: auctex, query-replace, narrowing

I am trying to come up with a Elisp function that narrows a buffer to a certain LaTeX enviroment (table, figures, ...), does some `query-replace-regexp` inside the narrowing, then searches for the next occurrence of the environment and does the same, until the last occurrence of the environment.

I have come up with this:

```
(defun narrowtable ()
  "narrowing on table environment"
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (save-excursion  
    (search-forward "begin{table}")
    (LaTeX-narrow-to-environment) 
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (query-replace "X" "B"); Just some query-replace
    (widen)))
```

which works for fine the first occurence of {table}, but only for that.

I guess I misplaced `save-excursion` for this to work properly, or there is something other to improve?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try something like this:

```lisp
(defun narrowtable ()
  "Narrowing on table or figure environments."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward-regexp
            "\\\\begin{\\(?:table\\|figure\\)}\\(?:\\[[^]]*\\]\\)?" nil t)
      (LaTeX-narrow-to-environment)
      (query-replace "X" "B"); Just some query-replace
      (widen))))
```

Some comments:

1. Do not use `beginning-of-buffer` in Lisp code, use `(goto-char (point-min))` instead
2. You were missing the loop for continuous forward search
3. I used `search-forward-regexp` in order to match the environments `table` and `figure` incl. an optional argument